# How to morph two objects using geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

H i , we do have two meshes with same exact topology and we want to morph them together ( exactly like what happens with shapekeys ) with geometry nodes by a simple vertex weight control how we can do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the same topology, even the vertex indexes, it is relatively easy:

[image]

You can use *transfer attribute* in *Index* mode:

[image]

The problem may occur if you have the same topology, but the indices are messed up. In this case you can try to use *Transfer the vertex order* add-on:

https://bartoszstyperek.gumroad.com/l/copy_verts_ids

If two meshes have different vertices positions use editmode Copy vert ID from sidebar:

[image]

First you need to select two, adjacent faces on source mesh - copy mesh id's, and then, select two similar faces on target mesh and paste IDs. Operation has to be repeated for each island (disconnected mesh parts)  separately.

> i want this to happen with the control of vertex weights, can you
> edit your answer and add the ability to control this with vertex weights

Vertex weight is an attribute, you can use *named attribute* to get it:

[image]

Comment: can i hug u ? no seriously you made my day my friend  , but there is some thing missing here , i want this to happen with the control of vertex weights , can you edit your answer and add the ability to control this with vertex weights ?

Comment: @user256371 I've updated the answer