# Where is named attribute blender 3.1.2?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

Sorry for this real nonsense question of mine but can someone tell me where is (or how to accomplish ) named attribute in blender 3.1.2 ?
the reference question is here where it has been used : [How to morph two objects using geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267181/how-to-morph-two-objects-using-geometry-nodes/267186?noredirect=1#comment456521_267186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node `Named Attribute` is available since **Blender 3.2**.

To put it precisely:

The following additional nodes have been (among others) added in this version:

- [Named Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/named_attribute.html)
- [Store Named Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/store_named_attribute.html)
- [Remove Named Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/remove_named_attribute.html)

[Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2/Nodes_Physics#Geometry_Nodes)

PS: As an alternative you can go the way over `Group Inputs` in *Blender 3.1.2*, with which you can also process *Named Attributes* in *Geometry Nodes*.

---

By the way, here is a helpful overview that illustrates which nodes can be found in which Blender version: [Geometry Nodes Overview](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)